# Catalogue page on My Ios flutter app not loading

Tags: ios, flutter, api

How do I configure the Firewall and security settings on a vps and also how to configure correctly a vps to allow my flutter app to access all the back-end api's , The other pages are working fine except the catalogue pages (it's supposed to display catalogue specials for different shops) is it possible that the catalogue api is being blocked from loading on iOS devices?

When I build the same flutter app code for android it runs perfectly fine, but when it comes to ios, it doesn't this particular page (catalogue).

Comment: Apart from that you can get multiple properties from connected Device. use for flag variable set in ios .......... UIDevice.current.name             // e.g. "My iPhone"
 UIDevice.current.model            // e.g. @"iPhone", @"iPod touch"
 UIDevice.current.localizedModel   // localized version of model
 UIDevice.current.systemName       // e.g. @"iOS"
 UIDevice.current.systemVersion    // e.g. @"15.5"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.